# iPhone home screen bookmark & persistent cookie

Tags: cookies, iphone, homescreen

When a webpage is bookmarked on the home screen of an iPhone, persistent cookies seem to get lost each time the app is opened. Is there a way to keep the cookies alive?

Comment: Met exactly the same problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem on iPhone 3GS, website is on jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone supports [localStorage](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/ch05.html), I would suggest using this for simple key/value persistent storage.

Comment: @stuart yes but how do you pass the session present in "localStorage" in request header when one click the home screen shortcut

Comment: just for example something like gmail which redirect user to there current gmail page without asking them to login again